# Error in Bulk Pattern SOQL

Tags: apex, soql, bulkification, queueable-interface

I am getting an error in the for loop.

> Error: Variable does not exist: acclist

```
public class AddPrimaryContact implements Queueable {
Private Contact conl = new Contact();
Private String sty;
Public List<Contact> coninsert = new List<Contact>();

public AddPrimaryContact(Contact conlist, String str)
{
    this.conl = conlist;
    this.sty= str;
}


public void execute(QueueableContext context)
{
    for(List<Account> acclist: [Select id,name from Account where BillingState =:sty]);
    {
        for(Account accops:acclist)// Error in this statement
        {
            conl.lastname = 'testLast';
            conl.accountid = accops.id;
             coninsert.add(conl);
        }
    }

    if(coninsert.size()>0)
    {
        insert coninsert;
    }
}}
```

Comment: Sorry my bad!
There is a semi colon after the for statement.
It took 1 hour to figure that . ...LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two for loops doing the same thing (along with some syntax issues), you only need one of them.  You execute method should look like this

```
public void execute(QueueableContext context)
{

    for(Account accops : [Select id,name from Account where BillingState =:sty])
    {
        conl.lastname = 'testLast';
        conl.accountid = accops.id;
        coninsert.add(conl);
    }

    if(coninsert.size()>0)
    {
        insert coninsert;
    }
}
```

Comment: @SFDC_BigDog: N.B. I believe the `if(coninsert.size()>0)` test is completely superfluous - no DML burned on empty lists.

Comment: Good point.  Was jut looking at the error but you are absolutely right

Comment: That is confirmed platform behavior. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/19399/2995

Answer (score -1):

Mistake was to write List in first for loop. 
Only one for-loop is required. Just understand below code.

```
public class AddPrimaryContact implements Queueable {
    Private Contact conl = new Contact();
    Private String sty;
    Public List<Contact> coninsert = new List<Contact>();

    public AddPrimaryContact(Contact conlist, String str)
    {
        this.conl = conlist;
        this.sty= str;
    }


    public void execute(QueueableContext context)
    {
        // while doing query at forloop, at return List of sObject, and a forloop always iterate over list (collection)
        for(Account accops:[Select id,name from Account where BillingState =:sty])// Correction here : 
        {
            conl.lastname = 'testLast';
            conl.accountid = accops.id;
             coninsert.add(conl);
        }

        if(coninsert.size()>0)
        {
            insert coninsert;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The for loop pattern in the post is one of the supported ones - see [SOQL For Loops](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for_SOQL.htm). (Someone down-voted without explaining why - presume it was because of this.)