# Handler will not compile

Tags: apex, compile-error

I got advice earlier today on how to separate my handler class's concerns so that I can test them better.

I cannot get the class to compile and it's killing me inside. The idea is that when a record is edited the there is a method to filter the records and then another method to do things with that filtered list.

When I try to save I get the error on this line:

```
List<Revenue_Pipeline__c> filtered = filterUpdate(newMap, oldMap);
```

> Illegal assignment from void to List Line 18.

This is what I have thus far, can you help me understand how I can pass the value of the query to the list so I can pass the values to the separate methods?

```
    public override void afterInsert(Map<Id, SObject> newMapGeneric){
        Map<Id, Revenue_Pipeline__c> newMap = (Map<Id, Revenue_Pipeline__c>) newMapGeneric;
        /*AFTER INSERT METHODS START*/
        if(!isRecursive)
        {
            isRecursive = true;
            createRevSchedule(newMap);
        }
        /*AFTER INSERT METHODS END*/
    }
    public override void afterUpdate(Map<Id, SObject> oldMapGeneric, Map<Id, SObject> newMapGeneric){
        Map<Id, Revenue_Pipeline__c> oldMap = (Map<Id, Revenue_Pipeline__c>) oldMapGeneric;
        Map<Id, Revenue_Pipeline__c> newMap = (Map<Id, Revenue_Pipeline__c>) newMapGeneric;
        /*AFTER UPDATE METHODS START*/
        if(!isRecursive)
        {
            isRecursive = true;
            List<Revenue_Pipeline__c> filtered = filterUpdate(newMap, oldMap);
            System.debug('filtered is:: ' + filtered);
            deleteSchedule(filtered);
            createScheduvoidle(filtered);
        }

    public static void filterUpdate(Map<Id, Revenue_Pipeline__c> newMap, Map<Id, Revenue_Pipeline__c> oldMap)
    {
        List<Revenue_Pipeline__c> revPipeline = new List<Revenue_Pipeline__c>();
        // Check if the fields changed

        for(Revenue_Pipeline__c revPipe : newMap.values())
        {
            if(
                revPipe.Product_Start_Date__c       != oldMap.get(revPipe.Id).Product_Start_Date__c ||
                revPipe.Product_End_Date__c         != oldMap.get(revPipe.Id).Product_End_Date__c ||
                revPipe.Product_Price__c            != oldMap.get(revPipe.Id).Product_Price__c ||
                revPipe.Weighted_Product_Price__c   != oldMap.get(revPipe.Id).Weighted_Product_Price__c
            )
                {
                    revPipeline.add(revPipe);
                }
        }
        System.debug('revPipeline is::' + revPipeline);
    }

    public static void createRevSchedule(Map<Id, Revenue_Pipeline__c> newMap)
    {
        List<Revenue_Pipeline_Schedule__c> newSchedule = new List<Revenue_Pipeline_Schedule__c>();
        for(Revenue_Pipeline__c revPipe : newMap.values()) {
            Integer numOfMonths = revPipe.Product_Start_Date__c.monthsBetween(revPipe.Product_End_Date__c) + 1;
            Integer n = revPipe.Subscription_Type__c == 'Subscription' ? 1 : 0;
            for(Integer i=0; i < numOfMonths; i++) {

                System.debug('Weighted Product Price is:: ' + revPipe.Weighted_Product_Price__c);

                    Revenue_Pipeline_Schedule__c revSchedule = new Revenue_Pipeline_Schedule__c();
                    revSchedule.Amount__c = revPipe.Weighted_Product_Price__c/numOfMonths;
                    revSchedule.Date__c = revPipe.Product_Start_Date__c.addMonths(i + n);
                    revSchedule.Name = revPipe.Name + ' - ' + revSchedule.Date__c.year() + '-' + revSchedule.Date__c.month();
                    revSchedule.Revenue_Pipeline__c = revPipe.Id;
                    revSchedule.CurrencyIsoCode = revPipe.CurrencyIsoCode;
                    newSchedule.add(revSchedule);           
            }
        }
        if(newSchedule.size() > 0){
            try{
                insert newSchedule;             
            } catch (DmlException d)
            {
                for (Integer i = 0; i < d.getNumDml(); i++)
                {
                    Id parentId = newSchedule[i].Id;
                    //parentId.addError(d);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void createSchedule(List<Revenue_Pipeline__c> filtered)
    {
        List<Revenue_Pipeline_Schedule__c> newSchedule = new List<Revenue_Pipeline_Schedule__c>();
        for(Revenue_Pipeline__c revPipe : filtered) {
            Integer numOfMonths = revPipe.Product_Start_Date__c.monthsBetween(revPipe.Product_End_Date__c) + 1;
            Integer n = revPipe.Subscription_Type__c == 'Subscription' ? 1 : 0;
            for(Integer i=0; i < numOfMonths; i++) {

                System.debug('Weighted Product Price is:: ' + revPipe.Weighted_Product_Price__c);

                    Revenue_Pipeline_Schedule__c revSchedule = new Revenue_Pipeline_Schedule__c();
                    revSchedule.Amount__c = revPipe.Weighted_Product_Price__c/numOfMonths;
                    revSchedule.Date__c = revPipe.Product_Start_Date__c.addMonths(i + n);
                    revSchedule.Name = revPipe.Name + ' - ' + revSchedule.Date__c.year() + '-' + revSchedule.Date__c.month();
                    revSchedule.Revenue_Pipeline__c = revPipe.Id;
                    revSchedule.CurrencyIsoCode = revPipe.CurrencyIsoCode;
                    newSchedule.add(revSchedule);           
            }
        }
        if(newSchedule.size() > 0){
            try{
                insert newSchedule;             
            } catch (DmlException d)
            {
                for (Integer i = 0; i < d.getNumDml(); i++)
                {
                    Id parentId = newSchedule[i].Id;
                    //parentId.addError(d);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Delete Revenue Pipleine Schedule Records
    public static void deleteSchedule(List<Revenue_Pipeline__c> filtered)
    {
        List<Revenue_Pipeline_Schedule__c> revPipeS = [SELECT Id,
                                                                  Revenue_Pipeline__r.Id
                                                           FROM Revenue_Pipeline_Schedule__c
                                                           WHERE Revenue_Pipeline__r.Id In : filtered];

        delete revPipeS;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is written on line 18?

Comment: this line:             List<Revenue_Pipeline__c> filtered = filterUpdate(newMap, oldMap);

Comment: your filterUpdate method is returning void

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `return` keyword at end also replace the `void` with the type you are returning here it is `List<Revenue_Pipeline__c>`:

```
public static List<Revenue_Pipeline__c> filterUpdate(Map<Id, Revenue_Pipeline__c> newMap, Map<Id, Revenue_Pipeline__c> oldMap)
    {
        List<Revenue_Pipeline__c> revPipeline = new List<Revenue_Pipeline__c>();
        // Check if the fields changed

        for(Revenue_Pipeline__c revPipe : newMap.values())
        {
            if(
                revPipe.Product_Start_Date__c       != oldMap.get(revPipe.Id).Product_Start_Date__c ||
                revPipe.Product_End_Date__c         != oldMap.get(revPipe.Id).Product_End_Date__c ||
                revPipe.Product_Price__c            != oldMap.get(revPipe.Id).Product_Price__c ||
                revPipe.Weighted_Product_Price__c   != oldMap.get(revPipe.Id).Weighted_Product_Price__c
            )
                {
                    revPipeline.add(revPipe);
                }
        }
        System.debug('revPipeline is::' + revPipeline);
        return revPipeline;
    }
```

Make sure the return variable type and the return type (we write in place of void) must be same.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the return type on your `filter` method from `void` to `List<Revenue_Pipeline__c>`.

**No Joy**

```
public static void myfilterMethod(...)
{
    List<Revenue_Pipeline__c> filtered = new List<Revenue_Pipeline__c>();
    // filter logic
}
```

**Joy**

```
public static List<Revenue_Pipeline__c> myfilterMethod(...)
{
    List<Revenue_Pipeline__c> filtered = new List<Revenue_Pipeline__c>();
    // filter logic
    return filtered;
}
```

Comment: Looking at the methods is this separated enough to test thoroughly?

Comment: I would separate out the error handling on `insert` into a `safeInsert` method. Also note that [there is no reason to skip DML on empty lists](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/19399/any-reason-to-skip-dml-on-empty-lists).

Comment: What? what do you mean?

Comment: If you split out your `try`/`catch` logic into a separate method, it is much easier to induce a `DmlException`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify the below method

```
public static List<Revenue_Pipeline__c> filterUpdate(Map<Id, Revenue_Pipeline__c> newMap, Map<Id, Revenue_Pipeline__c> oldMap)
{
     List<Revenue_Pipeline__c> revPipeline = new List<Revenue_Pipeline__c>();
     // Check if the fields changed
     for(Revenue_Pipeline__c revPipe : newMap.values())
     {
            if(
                revPipe.Product_Start_Date__c       != oldMap.get(revPipe.Id).Product_Start_Date__c ||
                revPipe.Product_End_Date__c         != oldMap.get(revPipe.Id).Product_End_Date__c ||
                revPipe.Product_Price__c            != oldMap.get(revPipe.Id).Product_Price__c ||
                revPipe.Weighted_Product_Price__c   != oldMap.get(revPipe.Id).Weighted_Product_Price__c
            )
                {
                    revPipeline.add(revPipe);
                }
        }
        System.debug('revPipeline is::' + revPipeline);
        return revPipeline;
}
```