# How to avoid 'for' within a 'for' loop in sales force Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

Create a custom field called “Number of Locations” (its API name: `NumberofLocations__c`) on the Account Object (Data Type=Number).Create multiple contacts by Account depending on the NumberofLocations__c field.

Trigger

```
trigger ContactsCreation on Account (after insert) {
    list<contact> listContact = new list<contact>();
    map<id,decimal> mapAcc=new map<id,decimal>();
    for(Account acc:trigger.new){
        mapAcc.put(acc.id,acc.NumberofLocations__c);
    }
    if(mapAcc.size()>0 && mapAcc!=null){
        for(Id accId:mapAcc.keyset()){
            for(integer i=0;i<mapAcc.get(accId);i++){
                contact newContact=new contact();
                newContact.accountid=accId;
                newContact.lastname='contact'+i;
                listContact.add(newContact);
            }
        }
    }
    if(listContact.size()>0 && listContact!=null)
        insert listContact;
}
```

Comment: I don't know how you can avoid the for loop inside the first for loop but I think your map is useless. You can use the second for loop in the first loop through `Trigger.new`. It avoids using the same for loop twice and the use of the `Map`.

Comment: @MartinLezer The 2nd for loop can easily be avoided.

Comment: Just a warning - your `if` statements should be reversed, at the moment if the list is null they will attempt to dereference a null list to call `size()` before checking whether the list is null, throwing an exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot generate a list of child `Contact` records without a `for` loop. You can, however, simplify testing and maintenance by breaking out a few of these methods into a [`Service Layer`](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_patterns_sl).

A few notes:

- You should add error handling to any cross-object DML in your triggers.
- There's *[no need to check if the list is empty](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/19399/2995)*.
- It is faster to set all fields at time of SObject construction by passing in `name=value` pairs.

#### Service Layer

More atomic build methods:

```
public static List<Contact> buildLocations(List<Account> records)
{
    List<Contact> locations = new List<Contact>();

    for (Account record : records)
        locations.addAll(buildLocations(record.Id, record.NumberOfLocations__c);
        // this way you only have to unit test one loop at a time
    
    return locations;
}
public static List<Contact> buildLocations(Id accountId, Integer count)
{
    List<Contact> locations = new List<Contact>();
    
    for (Integer i = 0; i < count; i++)
        locations.add(new Contact(AccountId=accountId, LastName='Contact' + i));
        // faster construction
    
    return locations;
}
```

Error handling:

```
public static void safeInsertLocations(List<Contact> locations, Map<Id, Account> parents);
{
    if (locations == null) return;
    // this strategy is called a "guard clause"
    // you don't have to guard against an empty list though

    try
    {
        insert locations;
    }
    catch (DmlException d)
    {
        for (Integer i = 0; i < d.getNumDml(); i++)
        {
            Account parent = parents.get(locations[i].AccountId);
            parent.addError(d);
        }
        // this is a pretty standard approach
        // for mapping errors back to parent records
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate on the accId as you've already set it up and just add 1 to an integer variable that you set up at before the beginning of the loop. Change your code as follows:

```
trigger ContactsCreation on Account (after insert) {
    list<contact> listContact = new list<contact>();
    map<id,decimal> mapAcc=new map<id,decimal>();
    for(Account acc:trigger.new){
        mapAcc.put(acc.id,acc.NumberofLocations__c);
    }
    if(mapAcc.size()>0 && mapAcc!=null){
        integer i = 0;
        for(Id accId:mapAcc.keyset()){                
            contact newContact=new contact();
            newContact.accountid=accId;
            newContact.lastname='contact'+i;
            listContact.add(newContact);
            integer i++;           
        }
    }
    // if(listContact.size()>0 && listContact!=null)
    // No need to test for size() or null
        insert listContact;
}
```

That having been said, it's unclear to me what you intended to do with your map to begin with. Unless you've omitted part of your code, the map serves no purpose for the code in your trigger as the number of locations isn't used. Did you intend to nest the location number within a for loop to further sort your contacts or add this information to the contact perhaps?

Comment: Actually, I think he wants to create multiple contacts by Account depending on the `NumberofLocations__c` field. This is what the second for loop is supposed to do.

Comment: I agree and was editing my answer with comments along those lines. If that were the case, He'd need to know more than the number of locations. He'd need to have some kind of a map of locationId to acctId.

Comment: @MartinLezer you are right..thats the scenario

Comment: @crmprogdev I didnt understand this line from you code..consider In account  no.of location is 3...Interger i=0 is fine  then,  for(Id accId:mapAcc.keyset()) ...mapAcc.keyset() contains accountId....again you increment the 'i'...when it will come out from the for loop?...how you decide how many times your for loop as to run?!!!...

Comment: See [List or Set Iteration For Loops](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for_lists.htm?search_text=for%20loop) in the docs. It iterates over each element in the keyset and knows to stop when none remain in the set.