# Update of a child collection is not working

Tags: apex, batch, update

I have a detail page button on a Custom object which updates child collection records. In the extension I'm calling a batch to update the child records on a given criteria. The batch completes with no errors and the logs show that an `update List<Sobject>` call is made against an expected list of records with updated field values, but the changes are not persisted. Please advice!

Here's the code block:

```
List<MySObject__c> sobjectsToUpdate = new List<MySObject__c>();
        for (MySObject__c obj : objects) {             
            if ('Some complex condition here') {

                 if (obj.Type__c == 'Type 1' ) {
                     obj.Status__c = 'Status 1';                      
                 }
                 else {
                     obj.Status__c = 'Status 2';
                 }
                 obj.Date__c = Datetime.now();
                 sobjectsToUpdate.add(obj);                                 
            }
        }

        if (!sobjectsToUpdate.isEmpty()) {        
            System.debug(sobjectsToUpdate); // I have this collection logged, and the records are as expected
            Database.SaveResult[] res = Database.update(sobjectsToUpdate, false);
            System.debug('All save results: ' + res); //This one is not logged.
            for (Database.SaveResult sr : res) {
                System.debug('Save result: ' + sr); //Neither this one
            }               
        }
```

**Note:** When I execute the batch logic directly in my extension, the collection is updated.

**Edit:** After further troubleshooting I noticed that the provided code block works for every other value except for: `obj.Status__c = 'Status 1';`. I don't have Validation rules.

Comment: Maybe the batch doesn't find any record. Could you please post your code?

Comment: The batch finds recrds, and I can see in the logs that an update call is made. Like I mentioned, when I execute the batch logic directly in my extension, it works. /Same query, same logic, against the same record/

Comment: Have you wrapped this code in a try/catch? FYI **[you don't need to check if the collection is empty](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/19399/2995)**.

Comment: Yes, I have and I got nothing logged in the catch. Thanks for the note!

Comment: The object has no triggers, validation rules, process builder processes, or workflow field updates (I swear I'm forgetting another thing)?  Is your sObject the detail record in a master-detail relationship with a master record that has a roll-up summary field being updated?  Is `Status__c` a restricted picklist, and if so is `Status 1` one of the available options?

Comment: This one is true: Is your sObject the detail record in a master-detail relationship with a master record that has a roll-up summary field being updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this more of an extended comment that a clear-cut answer. But your comments suggest...

Your code says:

```
System.debug(sobjectsToUpdate); // I have this collection logged..
Database.SaveResult[] res = Database.update(sobjectsToUpdate, false);
System.debug('All save results: ' + res); //This one is not logged.
```

and there is mention of try/catch in the comments.

A governor limit exception thrown from the `Database.update` would be consistent with the code comments - logic such as triggers caused to run by the update would make that more likely - and a governor limit exception can't be caught so a try/catch would not help there.

I suggest you triple check that the batch does indeed "completes with no errors " and turn on logging and review the log file generated for each invocation of the `start`/`execute`/`stop` methods for reported errors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped me to locate the issue. This was the key: A governor limit exception thrown

Comment: @vortex Glad it helped.