# How to remove duplicate id updates in batch job?

Tags: apex, batch

I got this error while executing my batch job

> Duplicate id in list: 0062800000AqfihAAB

Here is my batch job:

```
Global class OpportunityStageChanges implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

Global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
   //String query = 'Select id,Amount, (Select OldValue, NewValue From Histories) From Opportunity where stage <> NULL';
   //String query  = 'Select Id, CreatedById, CreatedDate, Field, NewValue, OldValue from OpportunityFieldHistory ';

    String query = 'Select Id,Name,Amount,LightiningEd__Stage_change_from_Prospecting__c,(Select ID, CreatedDate,OldValue, NewValue from Histories)from Opportunity';        
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}
Global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Opportunity> scope) {
  List<Opportunity> opplist = new List<Opportunity>();
  for(Opportunity opp : scope) {

    for(OpportunityFieldHistory opfh : opp.Histories){
          system.debug(opfh.oldValue+'----'+opfh.NewValue+'-----'+opfh.CreatedDate );
          if(opfh.OldValue == 'prospecting' && opfh.NewValue == 'Qualification '|| opfh.NewValue == 'Closed Won'){

              opp.LightiningEd__Stage_change_from_Prospecting__c = opfh.CreatedDate;
              System.debug('Date Value' + opp.LightiningEd__Stage_change_from_Prospecting__c);
              opplist.add(opp);

        }        
    }
    if(opplist.size()>0){
          update(opplist);
     }
   }

}
Global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a `Map`.

```
Map<Id, SObject> recordsToUpdate = new Map<Id, SObject>();
for (...)
{
    recordsToUpdate.put(someRecord.Id, someRecord);
}
update recordsToUpdate.values();
```

Note that **[you don't need to check if a list is empty before performing DML on it](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/19399/2995)**. Please also note that you should use the `public` access modifier rather than `global` unless you actually need the latter (you don't for batch jobs nor scheduled).