# Too many DML 10000 in batch apex

Tags: apex, batch

I have a requierment where i need to update product values daily based on product extendent values. I created a batch apex as article extended values are more. I am getting  but still gettin 10001 DML exception. Here is the execute code  i

```
public class Article_Extendet_Values_batch implements database.batchable<sObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts, Database.Stateful {
    
    
    private String query;
    
    public Article_Extendet_Values_batch() {
        
        query = 'select Price__c, Article_Name__c, IdExt__c, Article__c,'
            +'Class__c, ExcludeFromLoyalty__c, LoyaltyPoints__c,LoyaltyRefundable__c,Type__c from Article_Extendet_Values__c';
        
        //system.debug('query'+query);
        
    }
    
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List <Article_Extendet_Values__c> scope) {
        // system.debug('articleid1scope'+scope);
        list<SCArticle__c> articleList = new list<SCArticle__c>();
        set <id > artid= new set<id>();
        
        for(Article_Extendet_Values__c art : scope)
        {
            artid.add(art.article__c);
        }
        
        list<ScArticle__c> mappedarticle=[select id,class__c,ExcludeFromLoyalty__c,
                                          LoyaltyPoints__c,LoyaltyRefundable__c,type__c,idext__c from ScArticle__c where id =:artid];
        
        for( Article_Extendet_Values__c extval  :scope){
            
            
            for(SCArticle__C a : mappedarticle ){
                
                a.Class__c = extVal.Class__c;
                a.ExcludeFromLoyalty__c = extVal.ExcludeFromLoyalty__c;
                a.LoyaltyPoints__c = extVal.LoyaltyPoints__c;
                a.LoyaltyRefundable__c = extVal.LoyaltyRefundable__c;
                a.Type__c = extVal.Type__c;
                a.IdExt__c  = extVal.IdExt__c;
                
                // system.debug('class'+ a.Class__c);
                articleList.add(a);
            }
            
        }
        
        
        if(articleList.size() > 0) {
            try {
                update articleList ;
            }
            catch (DMLException e) {
                throw e;
            }
        }
        
        update articleList ;
    }
    
    
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: The above-shared code does not contain any DML Statement, Looks like incomplete code. Please share the complete code. And Also What is the batch size ?!

Comment: batch size is just 10

Comment: Seems likely `artid` could contain `null` and lead to this issue. Note also that it is [not necessary to check for null before performing DML](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/19399/2995).

Answer (score 6):

There are *lots* of problems in this code. The proximate cause of the issue, however, appears to be in this section:

```
    list<ScArticle__c> mappedarticle=[select id,class__c,ExcludeFromLoyalty__c,
                                      LoyaltyPoints__c,LoyaltyRefundable__c,type__c,idext__c from ScArticle__c where id =:artid];
    
    for( Article_Extendet_Values__c extval  :scope){
        for(SCArticle__C a : mappedarticle ){
            // snipped
            articleList.add(a);
        }
        
    }
    
   update articleList ;
```

You are first running a query that may produce a large number of results. But then, you are iterating over two different sObjects in nested `for` loops and adding an item to `articleList` for every combination of an `Article_Extendet_Values__c` record and a `SCArticle__C` record.

That is almost certainly not what you should be doing - more likely, you should be correlating them based on the shared relationship on which your query is based - and it also multiplicatively increases the size of `articleList`, so that even fairly small query sets will hit 10,000 records.

You're also updating the same list twice because you've written the `update` DML both inside and outside guards that are totally useless and should be removed. That further doubles your DML limits usage.

Most likely, I think this batch should be written against `SCArticle__c` instead of `Article_Extendet_Values__c`, but that's just a guess based on what I see here.